# How to insert into a database with a primary key?

Tags: python, sqlite, sql-insert

I'm having trouble with some code in which I would like to enter a new item into a database. I have encountered two different problems when trying to use the insert function. I have searched for similar problems online, but each fix results in the alternative error occurring.

This is the code I have currently:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Wholesalers VALUES (NULL, ?)", (wholesaler))
```

I am unsure as to why it is not working, and I can't figure out how to get it to work for my scenario.

The Wholesaler table has two columns, WholesalerID and Wholesaler. The "NULL" value was what I found on another post on how to insert an item into a database with a primary key, so the database will automatically add the next primary key.

The error I get with the current code is:

```
Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 13 supplied.
```

The error I get when using `(wholesaler,)` instead of `(wholesaler)`:

```
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

Comment: what is the error that you get? also the structure of the table Wholesalers will be also useful

Comment: Why do you insert NULL as a value for a column?

Comment: Change to `(wholesaler,)` to make it a `tuple`, **note** the `,`! Read about [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple)

Answer (score 0):

> The "NULL" value was what I found on another post on how to insert an item into a database with a primary key, so the database will automatically add the next primary key.

A simpler way for that is to name the columns into which you want to insert data, and ignore the primary key. More importantly and as [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57664610/how-to-insert-into-a-database-with-a-primary-key#comment101779546_57664610), we need to add `,` for the argument to be a tuple, which seems to be expected by the method:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Wholesalers (Wholesaler) VALUES (?)", (wholesaler,))
```

I generally prefer naming the columns explicitely because depending on the order of columns to insert values in the right place is a bit brittle.

As for

> Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 13 supplied.

If the method expects a tuple but receives a string, iterating over it would yield its 13 characters instead of the intended single string.

Comment: When both specifically naming the column I am inserting data to and using a tuple, I still receive this error:
`sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.`
Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @cold it probably means that wholesaler is of an unsupported type. How do you make sure it's actually a string and not another tuple (or list)? What is the content of the wholesaler variable? I presumed it's a string but the errorsays it's not.

Comment: I'm using a TkInter entry widget to get the wholesaler variable. I believe this should automatically turn it into a string when using .get().

Comment: @coldOpposite Well, it would seem that this is not the case, as evidenced by the error message. Error messages are seldomly wrong, it almost certainly means that wholesaler does not contain what you believe it does. Use print or a debugger, or maybe something like `type(wholesaler)` to verify what it is.